# Why does a => 0 also return after my console.log? Javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to find the phone number whose digits sum to the largest number. I was able to get get the correct phone number but it returned with a => 0. I'm curious to know why that follow.

```
var allNum = ['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'];
console.log(allNum[highest_number_index]);
var sum;
var highest_Num;
var highest_number_index;



for (var i = 0; i < allNum.length; i++){
   allNum[i] = allNum[i].replace(/-/g, "");

   for(var j= 0; j < (allNum[i].length); j++){

       sum += parseInt(newNum[j], 10);
   }


   if (sum > highest_Num) {
       highest_Num = sum;
       highest_number_index = i;

   }

    sum = 0;

}
```

Comment: What's `newNum`? Also, how do you know it gets the right number if it returns zero?

Comment: you are using the highest_number_index before you have declared it. Check you logic first.

Comment: That is an error it should be allNum. 

After i enter console.log(allNum[highest_number_index]); I receive:
     963-481-7945
     =>0

Comment: Thank you Diwas!!! I was able to solve it.